# Car component - single word request

Tags: single-word-requests

I am not quite sure if this question is fitting here, as I am looking for one word and it's about cars. I have searched the internet and found nothing. I'm not even sure if there's a word for it. The word I'm looking for is the word for the thingy below the car door. Not below the car, it's kinda where you put your foot when you enter. Or, in a movie, where the bad-ass character puts his enemy's head and closes the door repeatedly. It's kind of next to the car seat, but it isn't really **in** the car. Hopefully there are some car experts here, though even a car expert might not have taken the time to find out what this little section is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to the [*door sill*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=car+door+sill&num=50) (Google image search as I can't find it defined anywhere sensible).

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_automotive_design#S) defines it as

> The body section below the base of the door openings sometimes called the "rocker panels", or "rockers".

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of a **running board.**  They are not that common on modern cars, but they have a rich history. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_board

Comment: Ah, exactly, only I'm looking for the modern equivalent. The one that's kind of right on the edge of inside and outside of the car.

Comment: The part of the coachwork that’s underneath the door itself is called the **sill** or a **rocker panel**. The Wikipedia has a Glossary of Automotive Design that has definitions for a lot of terms, and although you have to know the term to look up the definition, it’s short enough to browse.

Comment: Some pickup trucks still have running boards.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to the horizontal segment of the rocker panel, it's called a **sill**. In some cases this step-over area on top of the rocker panel has a flat (decorative) piece attached, which is called a **sill plate**.

https://www.carid.com/articles/rocker-panels.html

https://www.carid.com/replacement-door-sills.html